# How to correctly CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm for ECDsa in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, ecdsa, xml-signature

I have a `XMLDocument` that was signed with edcsa-sha384, out of the box .NET `SignedXml` does not support that algorithm, so I followed this article (https://www.scottbrady91.com/c-sharp/ecdsa-xml-dotnet) and called `AddAlgorithm` at the beginning of the program:

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(Ecdsa384SignatureDescription),
                          "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha384");
```

Before `AddAlgorithm`, `SignedXml` was able to `CheckSignature` just fine for `rsa-sha256`, it was able to go through the XMLDocument and perform the signature check without throwing any errors...

After `AddAlgorithm`, it throws an error on the very second line of the xml file... Does anyone know what else I am missing to get ECDsa-RSA-384 to work?

```
InvalidOperationException
 > There is an error in the XML document.
 > <MySpecialDoc xmlns='https://www.hello.com/world/1.0'> was not expected.

   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
```

The XML starts with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MySpecialDoc xmlns='https://www.hello.com/world/1.0' id="9baedc57-c4ef-41f5-8bdf-33fb14af3f71">
...
```

If you know an article on how to register custom algorithm, please share it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out the root cause of my error, it has nothing to do with how I `AddAlgorithm`, it was actually working perfectly. The error I was seeing was due to the namespace in my XmlDocument being different. I generated some C# object class which had the namespace coded against `1.1` and the XML I was reading was an older `1.0`!!!!

I spent a lot of time researching and getting ECDsa algorithm to work with `SignedXml`, there actually isn't that much information out there regarding this, so hopefully this answer will be able to help someone else.

To add unsupported algorithm to `SignedXml`, you must first create a `SignatureDescription` class, then register for `SignedXml` to use via `CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm`.

This is an example of `SignatureDescription` for ECDsa P-384, tested in .NET 8 at the time of typing this. Code for `Ecdsa384SignatureDescription.cs` (you **may** wrap it around the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace, but not sure if that would clash if .NET actually provide the implementation):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class ECDsaCngSignatureFormatter : AsymmetricSignatureFormatter
{
    private ECDsaCng? key;

    public ECDsaCngSignatureFormatter(ECDsaCng key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public override void SetKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm key) => this.key = key as ECDsaCng;

    public override void SetHashAlgorithm(string strName) { }

    public override byte[] CreateSignature(byte[] rgbHash) => key!.SignHash(rgbHash);
}

public class ECDsaCngSignatureDeformatter : AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter
{
    private ECDsaCng? key;

    public ECDsaCngSignatureDeformatter(ECDsaCng key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public override void SetKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm key) => this.key = key as ECDsaCng;

    public override void SetHashAlgorithm(string strName) { }

    public override bool VerifySignature(byte[] rgbHash, byte[] rgbSignature) => key!.VerifyHash(rgbHash, rgbSignature);
}


public class Ecdsa384SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription
{
    public Ecdsa384SignatureDescription()
    {
        KeyAlgorithm = typeof(ECDsaCng).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    }
    public override HashAlgorithm CreateDigest() => SHA384.Create();

    public override AsymmetricSignatureFormatter CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        if (!(key is ECDsaCng ecdsa) || ecdsa.KeySize != 384)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Requires EC key using P-384");
        return new ECDsaCngSignatureFormatter(ecdsa);
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        if (!(key is ECDsaCng ecdsa) || ecdsa.KeySize != 384)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Requires EC key using P-384");
        return new ECDsaCngSignatureDeformatter(ecdsa);
    }
}
```

Once you've created the class, you need to register it somewhere in your program, to do so:

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(Ecdsa384SignatureDescription),
                          "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha384");
```

You should be able to sign and verify signature with ECDsa P-384 now.